# Unity - Box Collider not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I have 2 Box Colliders(green boxes) and a ball in my scene. Whenever the ball touches the bigger Box Collider *the player dies and the game is over*. However, if the ball is on the smaller collider(as it is in the pic), the player is fine and the game continues to run.

**PROBLEM**

When I drop the ball from a height, sometimes the ball manages to touch the bigger Collider(maybe because of its momentum) and *my player dies*. As I said this doesn't happen always which is resulting in an unpredictable outcome.

**WHAT I DID TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM**

I added `rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;` to stop the ball as soon as it collides with the smaller `Collider`. But it didn't work.

*light* is the `tag` associated with the Game object that has smaller Box Collider attached to it.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("light"))
        {

            Debug.Log("collision");
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            return;
        }
        // Zero out the ball's velocity
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;

        Debug.Log("gameovercollision");
        // If the ball collides with something set it to dead...
        isDead = true;
        //...and tell the game control about it.
        GameController.instance.PlayerDied();
   }
```

I even tried releasing the ball from the same height but still, the behavior was unpredictable.

**LOGS**

> **gameovercollision**
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Ball:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Ball.cs:63)
>
> **collision**
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Ball:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Ball.cs:54)

- What's the reason for this behavior?
- Why does not the smaller  Collider stop the ball perfectly?
- How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's because the velocity of the ball is high enough to enter both colliders after a single fixed timestep.

Try to decrease the `Fixed Timestep` value under Project Settings -> Time and/or set the `Collision Detection` field of the ball's rigidbody 2D to `Continuous`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I have just started learning unity so I am trying to figure out how things work in Unity. So, Why does not the smaller `Box Collider` stop the ball (since it is above the bigger `Collider`)?  Logs too show that the ball is touching the bigger collider first and then the smaller one. How is this possible? The smaller Collider is above  So, the ball should touch smaller one first.

Comment: And how decreasing `Fixed Timestep` solves the problem.